# Getting a string between two string with sed

Tags: sed, grep

I need to extract (With sed or grep) a substring between two strings.

The problem is that the strings before and after are html tags with double quotes, spaces, etc...

This is an example of a line where i want to extract the text:

```
12pt;">TEXT_TO_GET</span></div></message>
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superficially, you could use `sed`:

```
sed 's%12pt;">\(.*\)</span></div></message>%\1%'
```

or:

```
sed -n '/12pt;">\(.*\)<\/span><\/div><\/message>/ s%12pt;">\(.*\)</span></div></message>%\1%p'
```

The first prints out non-matching lines unchanged; the second only prints out matching lines.

However, this is looking for a very rigid context; if that's exactly what you want, it is great, but if you need to vary things, it gets messy quite quickly.  However, without any indication of what variations need to be accommodated, it is not possible to give a more flexible answer reliably.

Comment: Nop, that sed prints the whole line, i only need to print the text in the middle (TEXT_TO_GET in the example), i need the output to be only it. There are no variations, i get some lines from a file, grep them and get some output, -most of it html- and i need to extract a substring as i said in the first post. The "before and after" substrings will be always the same (The ones i put there)

Comment: Now, reading your post again, i thik you didn't understand the problem xD; what i put in the first post is NOT the entire line, is just a part of it, there are more things before, but those substrings only appear once, always in that order, etc etc.

Comment: Both of those commands, when fed your line of input, give you `TEXT_TO_GET` as the output.  The difference between them is if there are other lines that don't match the pattern.  The first command then echoes those other lines (unchanged), and the second doesn't echo them.  That seems to be what you are requesting in the question and in the comments...did you try what you I gave you?

Comment: Yes, i tried it and returns all the rest of the line, but don't worry i figured out another way of doing it, with 2 seds (sed -n -e 's/.*12pt;">//p' | sed -n -e 's/<\/span>.*//p'); thanks a lot anyway! :)

Comment: Which version of `sed` on which platform are you running?  I copied and pasted the commands from the answer and they worked fine for me on Mac OS X 10.8.4 using the BSD `sed` provided, and also with GNU `sed` 4.2.2.  Of course, if there is junk on the line before the `12pt;` part, then you have to clean that up; if there is junk after the `</message>` part, then you have to clean that up.  But the question didn't mention that as a possibility.  Be careful what you ask for; you might get exactly what you said you wanted, not what you meant you wanted.

Comment: I never said that was the only thing in the string, you ASSUMED that; my question was very clear "To get a String between two substrings"; your answer didn't do that, your answer deletes those two substrings from the line and echos the rest, and that WASN'T WHAT I ASKED FOR. So, don't blame me if you didn't read my question.

Comment: We'll have to agree to differ on the question then; I don't agree with your analysis of what you asked for. Please learn about how to ask questions so that there is no chance of them being misinterpreted (or minimal chance). You could have helped your cause by showing a couple of examples of the input. You gave one example input (and required us to interpret the output — not hard, but not explicit). If you give two or three example inputs and the expected outputs, you'll get better answers. I did note that I was giving an answer that was only superficially correct because of lack of info.

Comment: Brother, that happened because you should have strictly sticked to my question ('How to get a string between two strings'). You tried to give a "solution" to a problem i never asked you about, and in that process, you made your own assumptions. In my first post i clearly said: "This is an example of a line", it could have been a generic example ("AAATEXTBBB") and the question is ALWAYS the same: "¿How can i get a string between two strings?". So i insist, thanks a lot for your help, but don't blame me if YOU make a wrong assumption